# How Many Different Ways Can I Kill Raptors?

Tags: raptor-safari

So I'm playing the web version of [Raptor Safari](http://blurst.com/raptor-safari/), and it dawns on me that I've been slaughtering raptors in a large variety of different ways, all of which have been generating different amounts of score.  Which brings me to the question:

Does anyone have a complete list of all of the different ways you can snuff out a raptor, and approximate score values that are generated for successful completion of each method?

Here is a taste of some of the different methods.

---

[image: Roadkill]

**Roadkill**

---

[image: Epic Roadkill]

**Epic Roadkill**

---

[image: Clean Hit]

**Clean Hit** (Hitting a Raptor with just the Spikey-thing, without throwing it.

---

[image: Toss]

**Toss** (Hitting a Raptor with just the Spikey-thing after releasing it.)

---

[image: Wheeee]

**Wheeee!**

Comment: Every time I feel pride about the awesomeness and unique features of the obscure games I play, you have to 1up it with things even more ridiculous. I commend you for this.

Comment: The raptor is *driving* the jeep! http://goo.gl/6QlBK

Comment: They look less like Raptors and more like Archaeopteryx to me. Albeit a lot larger. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeopteryx - Saying that, Archaeopteryx Safari doesn't really roll off the tongue.

Comment: The Raptor driving the jeep has a monocle.  He means business.

Comment: Somehow, I managed to notice the monocle yet remain completely unfazed.  What the hell is wrong with me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll post some kills you haven't mentioned, as well as acts that do not seem to count as special kills. This list gets updated as I find new ways to maim raptors. Pictures will be added if I remember to capture the moment. You can see the points for each kill in the pictures, so they approximate how much each kill is worth. Kills are sorted from being on average worth the least to the most.

**Special Kills**

---

**Flying Raptor!** (Launch a raptor into to air after killing them.) Boosting helps with these kills, notice the poor chap near the bottom left. Points are awarded based on distance (not pictured, this is before the Flying Raptor! finished). Because you can add this to any kill I recommend trying for it every time:

[image: Wheee!]

---

**Killed!** (Kill a raptor with an impact without hitting them with your car.) As Gnome Slice pointed out, driving a crate into a raptor will get this kill.

[image: Weird.]

---

**Clothesline!** (Kill a raptor with your chain.) Not worth many points as it's very easy to do, even easier than tossing:

[image: Give 'em the chain.]

---

**Raptor on Raptor!** (Hit one raptor into another.) Fun fact, you can stick more than one raptor on your spiky ball then toss all of them. Bonus points for more throwing more than one (see below the picture for how to do this), but no new shiny text. You can see I hit one with three others in the picture, and it's worth a decent number of points. However, it's hard to drive with three raptors on your jeep:

[image: One big family.]

To chain raptors, kill how ever many raptors you want on your chain by tossing a new ball per raptor. Then drop one last ball out and roll over each of them collecting a longer and longer chain. You have to do this because each ball can only stick to two raptors at a time, so this uses a ball per raptor to get the job done. Then you can swing around a ridiculous chain of death to nail other raptors, but it's not worth as many points and it is fun.

---

**Siamese Raptors!** (Hit a raptor with the spiky ball when another raptor is stuck on your spiky ball). Worth slightly more points than Raptor on Raptor!, but also difficult to do. Raptors omitted from the picture to save their dignity:

[image: Ouch.]

---

**Pushed In! Live Specimen!** (Push a raptor into the exporting beam. Live Specimen is achieved if you don't kill them in the process.) Pushed In! provides a meager number of points, but Live Specimen! is high into the tens of thousands. You can herd raptors like cattle into the beams to get Live Specimen! with ease:

[image: Beamed!]

---

**Jumpkill!** (Jump and land on top of a raptor.) Points are proportional to the distance you traveled and are well worth the effort:

[image: Aftermath of landing on a raptor. Where'd he go?]

---

**Holy Pterosaur!** (Kill one of the three flying Pterosaurs.) This is allegedly difficult to do. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iajFi7h5ghI) shows a great way of getting all three. If you're awesome, you kill them with your spiky ball:

[image: Flying can't save you now!]

Figure that one out.

---

Now, for kills that don't seem to count:

- Backing up into a raptor. Don't waste 10 minutes like I did trying to do it.
- Ramming a raptor into a rock or tree. It counts as whatever special kill you performed with no bonus to smashing them into terrain. Will test a little more when I can sandwich a raptor closer to a cliff-side.

Comment: Killing a raptor with a crate gave me the *Killed!* award.  :)

Comment: Solid! I will correct my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @GnomeSlice To let you know ahead of time killing the pteradons is worth an incredible number of points. There is a tutorial on doing it here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iajFi7h5ghI. I won't post it in my answer until I have a picture of me doing it myself :P

Comment: @thethinman I've done it once before.  :P

Comment: @thethinman Can you get a screenshot of *Landmined!*?  I've only been able to do it twice, and both times were bad photo-ops.  :(

Comment: I'll be home at 6 and get one for you.

Comment: @thethinman I'm awarding the you the bounty in good faith that you will continue to update the list.  Otherwise, it will expire, and you deserve it anyway.  :)

Comment: @GnomeSlice Ohhh I totally forgot to post Landmined! I spent 4 minutes laying a big field of them then chasing poor raptors into it :D your faith is well placed, sir.

Comment: @thethinman For the record, backing into a Raptor gives a kill. I also haven't been able to reproduce the crate-kill again.  :/

Comment: @GnomeSlice wuuut, I must've messed up backing into him, maybe I hit at a bad angle.

Comment: @thethinman You can also get a **Pushed In!** award for a non-live specimen.  You just have to push a dead raptor in with the front of your truck.  You might be able to get a **Thrown in** too, but I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I described that in Pushed In!, saying that Live Specimen is only achieved if you push them in when they're still alive.

Comment: @thethinman My bad.  I'm still waiting for **Landmined!** too.  :)

Comment: Darggggh. I have work this week! I don't get home until like 10! You know, all these comments make me think we should launch your raptor-safari.stackexchange.com :D

Comment: @thethinman Waaaiiitttiiinnnggg...

Comment: I am officially a badass. You asked for Landmined, I Landmined a *pterosaur*. thinman delivers