# How Can I Help My Driver?

Tags: harms-way

When I'm playing as the gunner of my team in [Harm's Way](http://www.giantbomb.com/harms-way/61-33354/), a free XBLA title, I routinely get a notification on my screen that says:

> ***Your Driver Needs Help!***

What kind of trouble is my driver in?  Is he under fire?  Or has he merely been bumped?  Gone off the track?  Maybe just fallen back a position in the race?  Knowing what triggers these notifications would make it much easier to 'help' my driver.

Comment: You should ask [how many ways you can gun down a driver](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/how-many-ways-can-i-run-over-those-raptors) :D

Comment: I hope I don't get the bounty pawned off to me again ... maybe I should delete my answer because it seems to be soaking the votes. Is it 100% wrong?

Comment: @Sadly Not > You said yourself that you are "not entirely sure" about your answer.  :)

Comment: Not entirely sure doesn't mean wrong :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the notification when your driver is under fire from another turret.

Be sure to position yourself so that you can shoot players in other turrets and stop them from hurting your driver. You will be able to see other players controlling turrets marked with their screen name:

[image: Gunner perspective, showing enemy players AridSpider and coma buNNy controlling two other turrets]

In the picture above you can see that AridSpider and coma buNNy are in turrets that are attacking drivers (friendly marked in green). Firing at these turrets will prevent other players from using them, saving your poor driver.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vhm-hYVSlU) has many examples of the notification popping up, all when the driver is damaged by another player's turret.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I haven't been able to recreate this reliably.

Comment: @GnomeSlice It's based off a number of videos where it only happened occasionally. So not entirely sure, especially since I don't have an xbox :(

Comment: Updated. I think it's right now.

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression it happens when your driver is under fire, but I haven't confirmed it.

Most of the time, I 'ignored' it by just trying to blast away competition (turrets first then cars).